# CJKvert affecting all CJK in document

Tags: environments, unicode, cjk

My document has been compiling very well (thanks in no small part to Tex SX!), but I seem to have hit a snag. I added a more complicated dedication to the beginning of my thesis (using `\dedication \input{foo.tex}`). In the dedication I have some Chinese that I wanted to display vertically. I got that to work using the `CJKvert` package.

However, now it seems that all of my Chinese text is displaying rotated! I think this MWE shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{CJKutf8, CJKspace}
\usepackage[usebaselinestretch]{CJKvert}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\vspace*{-2cm}
\parbox[c][5em][c]{15cm}{%
\small In order to properly understand the big picture, we should fear becoming mentally clouded and obsessed with one small section of truth. \\%
\\%
Chapter 21 ``Dispelling Obsession'' \\%
The \emph{Xunzi} \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{turn}{-90}
\parbox[c][3cm][c]{24em}{%
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}\CJKvert\CJKtilde\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}荀子\\%
解蔽篇第二十一\end{CJK} \\%

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bkai}\CJKvert\CJKtilde\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}凡人之患，蔽于一曲，而闇于大理。\end{CJK}
}
\end{turn}
\parbox[c][5em][c]{15cm}{To my Cousin's Brother's\\%
Flatmate.
}
\end{center}

\chapter{Some Chapter Title}

The modern name of the People's Republic of China in Chinese remains
\emph{Zhongguo} {[}\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}中国\end{CJK}{]}
which translates most directly as ``central state'' or in literary
usage ``middle kingdom.''

\end{document}
```

Do I need to `\renewcommand` or some such after the dedication?

Ps. Please ignore the gross use of `\\` to get the spacing right. I am hardly concerned about that ATM.

EDIT 1:
I know this can perhaps be done more easily with xetex/xelatex and xeCJK, but that would break all of the rest of my Chinese, causing a great deal of recoding.

Comment: @cfr Sry bout that. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you just need to switch back to horizontal but perhaps I have missed something...

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{CJKutf8, CJKspace}
\usepackage[usebaselinestretch]{CJKvert}
\usepackage{setspace,rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{singlespace}
\vspace*{-2cm}
\parbox[c][5em][c]{15cm}{%
\small In order to properly understand the big picture, we should fear becoming mentally clouded and obsessed with one small section of truth. \\%
\\%
Chapter 21 ``Dispelling Obsession'' \\%
The \emph{Xunzi} \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{turn}{-90}
\parbox[c][3cm][c]{24em}{%
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}\CJKvert\CJKtilde\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}荀子\\%
解蔽篇第二十一\end{CJK} \\%

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bkai}\CJKvert\CJKtilde\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}凡人之患，蔽于一曲，而闇于大理。\end{CJK}
}
\end{turn}
\parbox[c][5em][c]{15cm}{To my Cousin's Brother's\\%
Flatmate.
}
\end{singlespace}
\end{center}

\chapter{Some Chapter Title}

The modern name of the People's Republic of China in Chinese remains
\emph{Zhongguo} {[}\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}\CJKhorz中国\end{CJK}{]}
which translates most directly as ``central state'' or in literary
usage ``middle kingdom.''

\end{document}
```

Is this right? (Bear in mind that I have no idea what it should look like.)

[image: Hopefully horizontal...]

Comment: Yes, that's what it should look like. Didn't know about `\CJKhorz` but guess it makes sense. Will report back asap.

Comment: That seems to work for the whole document, though I had to put it in the master.tex document after the `\dedication` but before the next bit of `\frontmatter` and all subsequent `\input{}` files.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it needed to be within the CJK environment so I echoed the way you'd used `\CJKvert`. Guessing really... ;).